hide annotation when clicking legend toggle
I'm using the annotation plugin to show a vertical line on my graph.
 const options = {
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          onClick: (e, legendItem, legend) => {
                    const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
                    const ci = legend.chart;
                    console.log(legendItem, legend);
                    if (ci.isDatasetVisible(index)) {
                        ci.hide(index);
                        legendItem.hidden = true;
                        if(legendItem.text === "Current Time"){
                           //toggle annotation off


                        }
                    } else {
                        ci.show(index);
                        legendItem.hidden = false;
                        if(legendItem.text === "Current Time"){
                            //toggle annotation on
                        }
                    }
                }
        },
        annotation:{
            annotations: [{
                display: true,
                type: 'line',
                borderColor: rs.getPropertyValue('--CURRENT_TIMELINE'),
                borderWidth: 2,
                mode: 'vertical',
                xMin: moment.utc().subtract(30, "m").valueOf(),
                xMax: moment.utc().subtract(30, "m").valueOf()
            }]
        }
    }


I have the options variable saved in state that i modify with my program:
<Bar options={this.state.options} data={this.state.data}/>

I understand the "this" keyword does not reference my object, but the chartjs legend when used in the callback. My question is this: I'm trying to figure out a way to toggle the annotation on / off this.state.options.annotation.annotations[0].display = false when the legend is clicked, preferably by using state, but since "this.state..." is undefined, i'm not sure how to do this. Is it possible?
Versions:
chartjs-plugin-annotation@3.1.0
react-chartjs-2@5.2.0

I don't know what version of chart.js you are using, in version 4 your options should have been under plugins, i.e., options.plugins.legend, options.plugins.annotations. In any case, you should be able to obtain the options as either e.chart.options or legend.chart.options; these should point to the same object, that should also be the object used to create the chart.

Thanks.  I'll take a look at this tomorrow.  I didn't see anything in legend.chart.options.  I didn't look too much at the event handler though.  Even if I am able to modify using the event handler, the problem still remains of transitioning it to state so my code doesn't override.

so i was able to find a toggle for the annotation under: legend.chart.config._config.options.plugins.annotation.annotations[0].display but the first two times the legend is pressed to hide/show dont work.  it takes a full toggle for the correct behavior to show up.

it also comes back as soon as anything modifies the object in state, since the event handlers dont update state.
